# ctypes: Memory management when returning pointers in COM Server

Tags: python, pointers, memory, ctypes, comtypes

I'm experienceing some strange issues since the transition from Win XP to Server 2008. I tried to fix these issues, however, I'm still not sure how memory management works through COM when returning pointers to structures.

Let's say I need to return something of type `POINTER(MyStruct)` in a function of a COM server written in Python. Within the function, I create the object:

```
struct = MyStruct()
struct.field = 4
```

then I return

```
return POINTER(MyStruct)(struct)
```

Do I have to keep a python reference to `struct` to avoid freeing the memory on the server before the marshalling takes place? If I actually do it, the COM client crashes. If I don't, sometimes data contained in these structs gets corrupted after reception at the client.

I guess I'm doing something wrong here but I couldn't figure out what by reading the [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) and [comtypes](http://starship.python.net/crew/theller/comtypes/server.html) documentation.

**EDIT1:**
I just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669074/python-ctypes-structure-being-overwritten-when-allocating-more-memory) post which seems to be related as there is the content of a structure being overwritten as well. The answer suggests what was expecting, too, namely that the memory is freed "accidentally". However, the answer does not explain *how* to solve this.

As I explained before, if I keep the reference like

```
self.struct = struct
```

the client crashes.

**EDIT2:**
I'm positing the COM interface definition and the python method signature on request by eryksun. In my question, I've simplified the problem a bit to make it easier to get an overview. The actual method returns a pointer to an array of structs:

```
IOPCItemMgt::ValidateItems
HRESULT ValidateItems(
[in] DWORD dwCount,
[in, size_is(dwCount)] OPCITEMDEF * pItemArray,
[in] BOOL bBlobUpdate,
[out, size_is(,dwCount)] OPCITEMRESULT ** ppValidationResults,
[out, size_is(,dwCount)] HRESULT ** ppErrors
);
```

Regarding the pointer on pointer `**`, interface specification says:

> You will note the syntax size_is(,dwCount) in the IDL used in combination with pointers to pointers. This indicates that the returned item is a pointer to an actual array of the indicated type, rather than a pointer to an array of pointers to items of the indicated type.

And this is the python method:

```
def ValidateItems(self, count, p_item_array, update_blob):
```

Assume that there is a ctypes struct called `OpcDa.tagOPCITEMRESULT()`.

I create an array of these structs by calling

```
validation_results = (OpcDa.tagOPCITEMRESULT * count)()
errors = (HRESULT * count)()
```

and after setting the fields of all array elements, I return the pointers like this:

```
return POINTER(OpcDa.tagOPCITEMRESULT)(add_results), POINTER(HRESULT)(errors)
```

**EDIT3:**
I want to sum up the comments to this post and what I've found out so far:

As eryksun suggested, a simplified return statement at least results in the same behavior and problems, but is more readable:

```
return add_results, errors
```

In the meantime, I did some experiments. I tried the low level implementation as eryksun suggested.

```
def ValidateItems(self, this, count, p_item_array, update_blob, p_validation_results, p_errors):
(...)
    p_validation_results[0].contents = (OpcDa.tagOPCITEMRESULT*count)()
    p_errors[0].contents = (HRESULT*count)()
    (...)
    for index (..)
        val_result = OpcDa.tagOPCITEMRESULT()
        p_validation_results[0][index] = val_result
        p_validation_results[0][index].hServer = server_item_handle
```

In the loop where I fill in the array elements, I've overwritten the contents with a new element, just because I'm was desperate. Interestingly, using this code I was able to see the memory corruption already on the server whereas the code before only reveals the corruption on the client-side.

- When `index=0`, `hServer` gets assigned its value. When I check the value, it's fine.

  When `index=1`, but before the assignment of `[0][1].hServer`, the value of `[0][0].hServer` is still fine.

  When `index=1`, but after the assignment `[0][1].hServer = val_result`, the value of `[0][0].hServer` has been corrupted in the same way as mentioned before.

  When `index=2` and **after** the assignment `[0][2].hServer = val_result`, the value of `[0][1].hServer` is fine

This means `hServer` only of the first array element gets partially overwritten after the second element is assigned a new value.

I assume that the memory for val_result of the first loop gets freed and overwritten somehow although I tought that the assignment `some_pointer[0] = new_value` actually copies the contents as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1470554) suggests.

But now, it get's even more strange. When I remember the `val_result` in a python list like e.g.

```
self.items.append(val_result)
```

the corruption on the server side is **gone**. But, I get the `COMError` on the client again.

The problem is, that this mysterious COMError is not caused by an (catchable) error in the server. Everything seems to work fine. So must be caused by the internals of COM mashalling.

Any suggestions how to proceed or to get some more insights on what happens inside COM?

Comment: `POINTER(MyStruct)(struct)` holds a reference to `struct` in the pointer's `_objects` attribute. The mistake in the linked question is casting a `bytes` object as a pointer without keeping a reference. It should be using `DISK_GEOMETRY_EX.from_buffer_copy`.

Comment: @eryksun If I return this pointer from a COM server, what happens to `struct`? Is the memory freed once the python method returns? In other words, do I have to keep a reference to the object or is it sufficient to return the pointer?

Comment: @eryksun I've added the information about the interface and method implementation to the initial question. PS.: As you might guess, I'm not using COM because it's so much fun ;)

Comment: Yeah, comtypes is doing that. E.g. if you need to return a pointer to an int, you simply return an int like `return 42`. Otherwise you'll get a type error.

Comment: @eryksun Interestingly, `return add_results, errors` works in terms of it does not throw a type error. However, it behaves similar to `POINTER(tagOPCITEMRESULT)(add_results), POINTER(HRESULT)(errors)` since the data the client receives gets overwritten partially as well. We also tried the low lever implementation. The type of the output arguments is `LP_LP_tagOPCITEMRESULT`. When we dereference the second level `p_validation_results[0][0]` we get a server-side NULL pointer error. Using `p_validation_results[index] = POINTER(tagOPCITEMRESULT)(tagOPCITEMRESULT())` results in client side error.

Comment: I tried `validation_results = (OpcDa.tagOPCITEMRESULT*count)()`, then populating the fields `validation_results[index].hServer = server_item_handle` and set the array like you suggested `p_validation_results[0] = validation_results`. Unfortunately this results in the same problem. The `hServer` of the first array element gets partly overwritten.

Comment: OK, that's just manually doing what the high level `return validation_results, errors` is already doing for you automatically.

Comment: Btw, using `p_validation_results.contents = cast(validation_results, POINTER(OpcDa.tagOPCITEMRESULT))` results in a client-side null pointer access error, so its obviously not equivalent to using the subscript operator.

Comment: [This post](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=BANLkTikTmi8CTYOWfCrxqqFvbP5_KKxC2w%40mail.gmail.com&forum_name=comtypes-users) seems to be related to our interface (though from the client's perspective) and it suggests using 1-indexed arrays. We tried to create a safe array with 1-based index. However, we get a type error `Cannot create SAFEARRAY type VT_RECORD without IRecordInfo.` using `p_validation_results[0] = _midlSAFEARRAY(OpcDa.tagOPCITEMRESULT).from_param(validation_results)`. Do you have any experience or ideas with this?

Comment: Sorry, forget about the SAFEARRAY. That is part of a different (automation-)interface. We've tried a lot of approaches and all boils down to the following: 1. If we return a pointer to the array, the contents get partially overwritten. We were able to see these changes even on the server-side 2. If we keep the python reference to the array, the contents remain unchanged (at least on the server-side), the server does not throw an exception but the client receives a COM error. How can we find out, what causes the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, I was almost about to resign when I got an answer from the Microsoft forum with a link to [an older thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d6f8735c-4d54-46e7-8060-88c894346257/cotaskmemfree-com-api-to-free-the-momory-crahses-on-windows7?forum=vcgeneral) which pointed me in the right direction. Actually, the thread starter solved its problem by using a `SAFEARRAY`, but if I'm not wrong, you cannot simply return a `SAFEARRAY` when a pointer to an array was requested. You'd have to change the interface which I couldn't. At least it did not work for me.

However, there was one line in his code snippet that got me thinking:

```
*ppServerId = (long*) CoTaskMemAlloc((*pSize) * sizeof(long));
```

The explicit call to `CoTaskMemAlloc` seems to be the counterpart to the method `CoTaskMemFree` that actually crashes on the client side. So I was thinking, that when the freeing routine in a 3rd party C++ software, that is supposed to work correctly for a lot of customers, crashes, that probably the allocation is wrong or missing.

So I was searching the comtypes sources for calls to `CoTaskMemAlloc` but could find any except one test case.

So I got it working by explicitely acllocating all memory for *anything* that is returned from a COM method via a pointer and not by value. That includes strings (`c_wchar_p`), structs, arrays and strings inside of structs.

So I wrote these three helper methods (that could actually be simplyfied a bit):

```
def make_com_array(item_type, item_count):
    array_mem = windll.ole32.CoTaskMemAlloc(sizeof(item_type) * item_count)
    return cast(array_mem, POINTER(item_type))

def make_com_string(text, typ=c_wchar_p):
    text = unicode(text)
    size = (len(text) + 1) * sizeof(c_wchar)
    mem = windll.ole32.CoTaskMemAlloc(size)
    ptr = cast(mem, typ)
    memmove(mem, text, size)
    return ptr

def make_com_object(object_type):
    size = sizeof(object_type)
    mem = windll.ole32.CoTaskMemAlloc(size)
    ptr = cast(mem, POINTER(object_type))
    return ptr
```

Then, I used it wherever I had to return any pointer.

So the `ValidateItems` method approximately looks like this now:

```
def ValidateItems(self, count, p_item_array, update_blob):

    validation_results = make_com_array(OpcDa.tagOPCITEMRESULT, count)
    errors = make_com_array(HRESULT, count)

    (...)
    for index (...):
        validation_results[index].hServer = server_item_handle

    return add_results, errors
```